# Lua / Initialize table with inline function code but assign value not function

Tags: lua, lua-table

I have this Lua code to initialize a table:

```
table = {
  a = 1;
  b = myfunc();
  c = function () <some code> end;
}
```

After this table.c has type function and I have to use `table.c()`
in a print statement with the .. operator to get the result. But I would like to just use `table.c` instead.

Is there a way that I can get the return value of the function assigned to table.c so the type is not function without having to define a function outside of the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanted `table.c` to contain the return value of the function, then you should have assigned it the *return value* of the function. You instead assigned it the function itself.

To get the return value of a function, you must call that function. It's really no different from `b`. `myfunc` is a function; `myfunc()` is calling that function and storing its return value.

But, due to Lua's grammar, calling a function that you are defining requires that you need to wrap the function constructing expression in `()`, then call it:

```
c = (function () <some code> end)();
```

This of course will only contain the value of that function at the time that the table is constructed.